# Find max and min date

Tags: python, python-2.7, max, min

I have a list with with dates. Currently I am interested only in the key 1 and 2 of each tuple. `month/year`

```
search_count=[(1L, 4, 2016), (3L, 5, 2016)]
```

I am trying this code, but in this way I only get the max and min year. I am interested in the combination of month and year.

```
min_date = min(search_count,key=itemgetter(2)) 
max_date = max(search_count,key=itemgetter(2))
```

How can I do that? Seem like i need two keys in min and max.

Comment: You could store your times as a timestamp in the format of `yyyyMMdd`, then sort the list and the max/min will be at both ends.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass multiple indices into `itemgetter`. First order by `2` (year), then order by `1` (month):

```
min_date = min(search_count, key=itemgetter(2, 1))
max_date = max(search_count, key=itemgetter(2, 1))
```